# ListViews background not being displayed if no items in it?

Tags: android, xml, listview, background

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=dextsh&s=6

I have created a listView with a white background. My problem is the following: the white background only gets displayed if the listview is full with items. How can I make the listView's background being displayed even if not any items in it?. What have I missed?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_search_task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:weightSum="1.0" 
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:background="@drawable/orginalbild">

<TableRow
    android:paddingTop="3dp">
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="0.04">
            </TextView>

            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/search_task_field"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:hint="@string/SearchTaskHint" 
                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/search_task_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.22"

                android:src="@drawable/find3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_weight="0.04"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                >
            </TextView>

        </TableRow>

 <TableRow
 android:paddingTop="3dp"
 android:paddingLeft="14dp"
 android:paddingRight="14dp"
 >
            <TextView
                android:background="#90767878"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0.9dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </TextView>

        </TableRow>

  <TableRow
     android:paddingBottom="20dp"
     android:background="#ffffff"
     >

          <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            </TextView>
           <TextView
                 android:background="#90767878"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.006" >
            </TextView>


          <ListView
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/search_task_list"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                 />

           <TextView
                 android:background="#90767878"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.006" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            </TextView>

         </TableRow>

     <TableRow>
           <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            </TextView>

           <TextView
                android:background="#90767878"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="0.9dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.92" >
            </TextView>

           <TextView

                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.04" >
            </TextView>

       </TableRow> 

    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: why you are using 0dip as layout width?

Comment: If you use 0dp, its width will be, well, 0dp if there are no items. That must be why you don't see the background.

Comment: Even if I change it to wrap_content or fill_parent the result is the same. Only thing that changes is the width of the white background (the background will be displayed from left to right). Still the background height is only displayed if the list is full with items....